# Matlab: Getting Random values from each column w/o zeros

Tags: matlab, random, vector, matrix, zero

I have a 2d matrix as follows:

```
possibleDirections =

 1     1     1     1     0
 0     0     2     2     0
 3     3     0     0     0
 0     4     0     4     4
 5     5     5     5     5
```

I need from every column to get a random number from the values that are non-zero in to a vector. The value 5 will always exist so there won't be any columns with all zeros.
Any ideas how this can be achieved with the use of operations on the vectors (w/o treating each column separately)?
An example result would be [1 1 1 1 5]

Thanks

Comment: I think this may be difficult without custom functions because the `randi` (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) function does not accept a vector of integers for different ranges.

Comment: I've uploaded the project to git: https://github.com/guywald/allele_fixation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without looping directly or via arrayfun.

```
[rowCount,colCount] = size(possibleDirections);
nonZeroCount = sum(possibleDirections ~= 0);
index = round(rand(1,colCount) .* nonZeroCount +0.5);
[nonZeroIndices,~] = find(possibleDirections);
index(2:end) = index(2:end) + cumsum(nonZeroCount(1:end-1));
result = possibleDirections(nonZeroIndices(index)+(0:rowCount:(rowCount*colCount-1))');
```

Comment: would you mind explaining what the syntax `[nonZeroIndices,~] = find(possibleDirections);` does? I've never seen it before...

Comment: @Floris [I,J] = find(X,...) returns the row and column indices instead of linear indices into X. The ~ is there to force this mode (but discard the column indices).

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution:

```
[r,c] = size(possibleDirections);

[notUsed, idx] = max(rand(r, c).*(possibleDirections>0), [], 1);

val = possibleDirections(idx+(0:c-1)*r);
```

If the elements in the matrix `possibleDirections` are always either zero or equal to the respective row number like in the example given in the question, the last line is not necessary as the solution would already be `idx`.

And a (rather funny) one-liner:

```
result = imag(max(1e05+rand(size(possibleDirections)).*(possibleDirections>0) + 1i*possibleDirections, [], 1));
```

Note, however, that this one-liner only works if the values in `possibleDirections` are much smaller than `1e5`.

Comment: don;t you need to take the `max` along the first dim? `max( ... ,[],1)`?

Comment: Isn't that the default of of `max`?

Comment: @Shai, @HMuster You are both right. Using `dim` argument is just safer in case you get a 1-row matrix.

Comment: @yuk  Ok, I added the explicit specification of the dimension. Thanks for the suggestion (Shai) and clarification (yuk).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code with two `arrayfun` calls:

```
nc = size(possibleDirections,2); %# number of columns
idx = possibleDirections ~=0;    %# non-zero values
%# indices of non-zero values for each column (cell array)
tmp = arrayfun(@(x)find(idx(:,x)),1:nc,'UniformOutput',0); 
s = sum(idx); %# number of non-zeros in each column
%# for each column get random index and extract the value
result = arrayfun(@(x) tmp{x}(randi(s(x),1)), 1:nc);
```